# How to calculate all MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, loops

```
+----------+-----------------------+
| id       | amount                |
+----------+-----------------------+
| 1        | 20                    |
| 2        | 40                    |
| 3        | 60                    |
```

i want to combine all amounts and end up with 120 ( 20 + 40 + 60 )
using php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $result = $row + $row; // of course false, just an example
 }
```

how to do it ?

Comment: Any reason you can't do it with a Mysql SUM()?

Answer (score 1):

You should do that directly in MySQL with the [`SUM` aggregate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TABLE;
```

Works then like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TABLE;';
list($sum) = mysql_fetch_row($query);
```

The benefit is that MySQL will calculate it for you and you do not need to transport all rows from the database into your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$sum = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $sum += $row['amount'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the sum of all the amounts:

```
 Select sum(amount) from table
```